# How to output table diff cleanly using SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, compare

I am working on a solution to help compare data between two tables. Say I have these two tables

```
Table: Clients_old
----------------------------------------------
ClientID    FirstName   LastName        Age
----------------------------------------------
1           John        Doe             20
2           Jane        Doe             20

Table: Clients_updated
----------------------------------------------
ClientID    FirstName   LastName        Age
----------------------------------------------
1           John        Doe             99
2           Jane        Smith           99
```

Right now, I'm using EXCEPT and some ugly case logic to output the differences above like so.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ClientID    FirstName_Old   FirstName_Updated   LastName_Old    LastName_Updated    Age_Old     Age_Updated
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1           NULL            NULL                NULL            NULL                20          99  
2           NULL            NULL                Doe             Smith               20          99
```

It's a start but I'd like to clean the output up. Given these two tables, is there a way in SQL to get the diff formatted like this?

```
-----------------------------------------------------
ClientID    ColumnName      OldValue    UpdatedValue
-----------------------------------------------------
1           Age             20          99  
2           LastName        Doe         Smith
2           Age             20          99
```

I have an idea of how to do it using C# but I'm curious if there is a SQL solution.

Answer (score 2):

You can unpivot in SQL Server.  For this, I might suggest:

```
with co as (
      select v.*
      from clients_old co cross apply
           (values (co.client_id, co.firstname, 'firstname'),
                   (co.client_id, co.lastname, 'lastname'),
                   (co.client_id, co.age, 'age')
           ) v(client_id, val, col)
     ),
     cu as (
      select v.*
      from clients_updated cu cross apply
           (values (cu.client_id, cu.firstname, 'firstname'),
                   (cu.client_id, cu.lastname, 'lastname'),
                   (cu.client_id, cu.age, 'age')
           ) v(client_id, val, col)
     )
select co.client_id, co.col, co.val as old_value, cu.val as updated_value
from co join
     cu
     on co.client_id = cu.client_id and co.col = cu.col and
        co.val <> cu.val;
```

The logic is slightly more complicated if `val` can be `NULL`.

Note that this approach does assume that the column types are all strings.  There are ways around this this, but the code is a little more complicated.

Comment: Awesome, I think this gives me a good starting point to work from. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

**Gordon's solution would be more performant.**

However, here is one approach which is not data type sensitive, and a bit more dynamic not having to specify the fields.

**Example or [dbFiddle](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=2d5e935ad2edecb182bcc2e01c7145ea)**

```
Select A.ClientID
      ,C.Field
      ,OldValue = max(case when Src='Old' then Value end)
      ,NewValue = max(case when Src='New' then Value end)
 From (
        Select Src='Old',* from Clients_old
        Union All
        Select Src='New',* from Clients_new
      ) A
 Cross Apply ( values (cast((Select A.* for XML RAW) as xml))) B(XMLData)
 Cross Apply (
                Select Field = a.value('local-name(.)','varchar(100)')
                      ,Value = a.value('.','varchar(max)') 
                 From  B.XMLData.nodes('/row')  as C1(n)
                 Cross Apply C1.n.nodes('./@*') as C2(a)
                 Where a.value('local-name(.)','varchar(100)') not in ('Src','ClientID')
             ) C
 Group By A.ClientID,C.Field
 Having max(case when Src='Old' then Value end) <> max(case when Src='New' then Value end)
        or  count(*)=1
```

**Returns**

```
ClientID    Field    OldValue   NewValue
1           Age      20         99
2           Age      20         99
2           LastName Doe        Smith
```

Comment: Good to know. Thank you. I'll try this one as well and see how much performance is a factor for what I'm comparing.

Comment: @ShawnM Please let me know.  I'm always interested in real word benchmarks.

Comment: @JohnCappelletti . . . As with many of your answers, this is quite a coup.  However, it is still data-type sensitive, because the resulting columns are varchars (and have to be the same time in the result set).

Comment: @GordonLinoff The final results are varchar but dates and numerics port over nicely.  However, if column X in table A and B have different datatypes the comparison would indeed fail.   I've used similar technique during my discovery/migration phases.

Comment: @GordonLinoff See updated dbFiddle for int and dates for example http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=4ff38a5d7171dfcf8b29e5bb26d19889

Comment: @JohnCappelletti . . . I *think* the conversion to date in my version would be the same.  The big advantage here is that you don't need to list the columns explicitly.

Comment: @JohnCappelletti I didn't forget! It's been a while since I got to work on this but I got to test this out with a data set that was about 11,000 records in each table I was comparing and it took about 30 seconds.